# Определение касаемого элемента

Tags: android, multi-touch

Старую проблему с несколькими почти решил, но осталось вот что:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent e)
{
    switch(e.getAction())
    {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            играем_звук;
            return false;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
            проверяем_какую_кнопку_мы_коснулись_и_играем_звук;
            return false;
        default:
            return false;
}
```

Проблема на данном этапе

```
case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN:
     проверяем_какую_кнопку_мы_коснулись_и_играем_звук;
return false;
```

Как реализовать проверку какой именно кнопки мы коснулись?

Т.е код должен работать так. У нас зажата кнопка 1. Мы кликаем кнопку 5, срабатывает событие из кнопки 1 (`MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_2_DOWN`), оно определяет, что мы нажали кнопку 5 и играет звук.

**Добавление.**

```
//Objects
final ArrayList<View> views = new ArrayList<View>();

views.add((View)Button1);
views.add((View)Button2);
layout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {  
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        switch(arg1.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            float X = arg1.getX();
            float Y = arg1.getY();
            for(View touchBtn: views) 
            { 
                float Left = touchBtn.getLeft();
                float Width = touchBtn.getWidth();
                float Top = touchBtn.getTop();
                float Height = touchBtn.getHeight();
                if(X > Left && X < (Left + Width))
                    if(Y > Top && Y < (Top + Height))
                        switch(touchBtn.getId())
                        {
                            case R.id.Button1:
                                mSoundManager.playSound(1);
                            break;
                            case R.id.Button2:
                                mSoundManager.playSound(2);
                            break;
                        }
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Неработает...

Comment: Решение проблемы так и не найдено...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю, этот вопрос не имеет положительного ответа. Если один вид содержит две готовые кнопки (вообще два пользовательских элемента каркаса), сообщения идут так:

1. нажат **первый** элемент - вызван onTouch для вида **первого** элемента,
2. нажат **второй** элемент - вызван onTouch снова для вида **первого** элемента.

Как следствие по координатам не удается установить, где произошло нажатие. И поэтому не получается использовать multi-touch поверх нескольких кнопок.

Comment: Показать прилы где это работает? 
По сути должно быть так. Я зажал кнопку 1. Должен нажимать на кнопку 2 и она должна отыгрывать.

Comment: Конечно, покажите. Всегда интересно узнать что-то новое и полезное. :)

Comment: https://market.android.com/details?id=com.bti.myDrums&feature=search_result 
Вот как в этих примерах должно работать
https://market.android.com/details?id=com.phellax.drum&feature=search_result

Comment: А почему Вы думаете, что это готовые кнопки?

Comment: А что еще?

Comment: Просто графика.

Comment: И в чем разница будет? Всеравно мультитач нужен

Comment: Разница в том, что сообщения будут идти внутри одного вида, в единой координатной системе, и по координатам можно будет определить, где произошло нажатие.

Comment: Ну и как тогда это реализовать, примерчик можно?

Comment: Вроде такого:<br/>
http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/detail?name=MTTest.apk&can=2&q=

Comment: Все также актуален данный вопрос...

Answer (score 0):

А случаем, в параметрах функции не передается ли View, на котором произошло нажатие?
Приводите тип View к типу вашей кнопки и работайте с ней, например, найдите по id необходимую. Что-то вроде:

```
Button b = (Button) v;

switch(b.getId()) {
case R.id.btn1:
    //play sound 1
    break;
case R.id.btn2:
    //play sound 2
    break;
}
```

Comment: Неработает. Зажимаю кнопку, и жму на другие которые мы определили, ничего не звучит.

Comment: А что у вас в качестве кнопок?

Comment: Обычные Button.

Comment: А если не делать проверку, какая кнопка нажата? Звук есть?
Можете попробовать выводить в лог какую-то информацию из "v" (using Log.i(...)), которая сможет помочь в определении того, что нажато.

Answer (score 0):

Совместными усилиями рук и мозга получилась вот такая ерунда:

```
package com.touch;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TestTouch extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        //
        mainView = findViewById(R.id.mainView);
        tvString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvString);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn1.setClickable(false);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn2.setClickable(false);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn3.setClickable(false);

        //
        views = new ArrayList<View>();
        views.add((View)btn1);
        views.add((View)btn2);
        views.add((View)btn3);
        //mainView.addTouchables(views); //не работает ... может кто в курсе, почему?
        Log.i("NUMBER OF TOUCHABLES", "" + views.size());
        mainView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {  
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                switch(arg1.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    float X = arg1.getX();
                    float Y = arg1.getY();
                    Log.i("COORDINATES", "X: " + X + "; Y: " + Y);
                    Log.i("NUMBER OF TOUCHABLES", "" + arg0.getTouchables().size());
                    for(View touchBtn: views) { //хотелось использовать for(View touchBtn: arg0.getTouchables()) //но массив пуст 
                        //Button touchBtn = (Button) arg0.getTouchables().get(i);
                        float Left = touchBtn.getLeft();
                        float Width = touchBtn.getWidth();
                        float Top = touchBtn.getTop();
                        float Height = touchBtn.getHeight();
                        //Здесь глупость, может, кто подскажет как оптимальнее определить находится ли точка над конкретным View
                        Log.i("COORDINATES", "minX: " + (Left) + "; minY: " + (Top));
                        Log.i("COORDINATES", "maxX: " + (Left + Width) + "; maxY: " + (Top + Height));

                        if(X > Left && X < (Left + Width))
                            if(Y > Top && Y < (Top + Height))
                                tvString.setText("Btn " + touchBtn.getId() + " down");
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //Objects
    private View mainView = null;
    private TextView tvString = null;
    private Button btn1 = null;
    private Button btn2 = null;
    private Button btn3 = null;
    private ArrayList<View> views = null;
}
```

Дело в том, что на самом деле непонятно, почему не работает функция setTouchables().
Если я все правильно сделал, эта функция является достаточно удобной в данном контексте.

Comment: btn3.setClickable(false);
вот это не забыли? иначе как я понял кнопки будут реагировать на ивенты onClick, а ивент onTouch возникать не будет

Comment: Забыл. Теперь новый баг, жму верхнюю часть кнопки - играет звук 3, жму нижнюю - играет звук 1. Оо

Comment: Надо разобраться с координатами. Покрутите логи, думаю, это будет вам проще сделать, чем мне гадать в чем проблема.